# how to delete firestore collection using cloud function

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

here i'm attaching my firestore structure.

[image]

i'm creating an android chat app which has a fetch to delete all chat in a single click, for that i've to delete a collection, which firebase doesn't allow without cloud collection.

i tried to create function to delete collection but wasn't successfull. can anybody help me.

Thank you in andvance

Comment: So you want code that deletes an entire collection? For example, you want to delete, `f44efb19...`?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes right

Comment: i don't want to run a loop at front end so want a google cloud function to do this job

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how you can achieve that.